# Learning PHP, Boolean algebra

Tags: php, boolean, algebra

So i've just started learning PHP and i came across a part i didn't quite understand.

The book gave me three lines.

> && and true && true=true, every other combination results in *false*.
>
> || or false || false=false, every other combination results in *true*.
>
> XOR or false XOR true=true, every other combination results in *false*.

If anyone can clarify what this means i would very much appreciate it.

**Edit**

the following is text above my previous part.

Every equation yields a value: either true(1) or false(0).

```
echo true + true + false
```

This results in a value of 2 (1 + 1 + 0).

Comment: Can you provide a little more context? "&& and true" is not a programming syntax I recognize.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are three boolean operators mentioned there: `&&` (logical AND), `||` (logical OR), and `XOR` (well, it's logical XOR, or 'exclusive OR'). All of these are binary ones - they take two operands. Its result, apparently, is a boolean value - either `true` or `false`.

Now, they function as follows:

- `&&` will only result in `true` if *both* its operands evaluate to `true`, otherwise the result will be `false`
- `||` will only result in `false` if *both* its operands evaluate to `false`, otherwise the result will be `true`
- `XOR` will result in `false` if its operands evaluate to the same value - be it `true` or `false`, doesn't matter. But if one operand evaluates to `false`, and another to `true`, the result is `true`.

---

Now, on the second part of your question: this...

```
echo true + true + false;
```

... doesn't have anything to do with boolean algebra. All the operands of `+` are cast to the numeric type first, by the rules described in [**Type Juggling**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php) section of the PHP documentation. In short, `true` is converted to `1`, `false` to `0`; the result - `1 + 1 + 0`, or `2`, is printed out.

Comment: +1 good explaination. See also [logic gates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logic_gate)

Comment: ah ok this makes a lot more sense. (btw i think you made a mistake on the || part (otherwise the result will be true)) but thanks for the great explanation.

Answer (score 1):

It is referring to the fact that `and` and `&&` etc. have different operator precedence.

Namely, `and` or `or` function differently than `&&` and `||` with assignment statements:

```
$f = false or true;
```

Also, the operators are short-circuit operators, so if you have something that evaluates to `false` as the first operand with either `and` or `&&` then the entire expression will immediately evaluate to `false` without evaluating any other operands.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php

Comment: Ah... This is a very helpful detail.